# Android. Imageview inside ScrollView

Tags: android, xml

[image]I have been trying to place two imageviews inside my android layout, but i cant get them placed like i want to. Therefore im looking for some help. Right now i have removed them from my gone, and gone "back to basic", but i have attached am image, where you can see the red marks, as symbols as where i want the imageviews to be. Please help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#111111"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/scr1"
android:scrollbars="none"
    >

     <RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/location" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/img1"
    android:background="#FCD2E6"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:text="view1"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="30dp" />



    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view3"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view4"
    android:textSize="15dp" />


     <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:id="@+id/rel2"
    android:background="@drawable/divider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dp" 
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view6"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView6"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view7"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view8"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView8"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view9"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view10"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView10"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#d3d3d3"
    android:text="view11"
    android:textSize="15dp" />

   </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
![Layout with the Imageviews][2]
```

Comment: Share the wireframe image.

Comment: <ImageView android:id="@+id/img2" android:layout_width="50dp" android:layout_height="50dp" android:scaleType="center"  android:src="@drawable/icon" />

Comment: Its like this. Then my problem is placing it correctly. Cant get it right

Comment: Can you share the image again? Because I don't see the image you talk about in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LinearLayout instead Relative because Linear has orientation property 'vertical' and horizontal. And ıf you post an image we can help you easily then this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place them together in a single Layout ( use relative layout)

```
   <RelativeLayout>
          <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/imageView1>
          <ImageView
               android:toRightOf="@id/imageView1>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

use torightof and toleftOf attribute to place the UI control in any direction relative to that particular element.